# Javascript positioning center style

Tags: javascript

I wanted to set my second div element indside of my first div element center. I think somehow I managed to center it. But I think I made some mistakes and it seems to me it is not properly centered and also this JavaScript style seems to me bad. Is there any better way doing it? Is my JavaScript code is correct?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2dGn4/7/)

**HTML**

```
<div class='first'>
    <div class='second'>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var first = document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0];
var second = document.getElementsByClassName('second')[0];
var height = first.offsetHeight;
second.style.width = height/2+"px";
second.style.height = height/2+"px";
second.style.marginLeft = height/4+"px";
second.style.marginTop = height/4+"px";
```

Comment: @ oGeez BECAUSE i want to learn pure javascript without any libraries and if there any solution with libraries it would be good

Comment: That's a fair comment. Please, if you are only looking for vanilla JavaScript solutions, don't use the jQuery tag.

Comment: The reason why it looks incorrect is because you have a 3px (total: 6px) border.

Comment: @ gladsocc it's true i've forgotten this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`offsetHeight` will get the height of the element including borders, `clientHeight` won't. Instead of:

```
var height = first.offsetHeight;
```

Try:

```
var height = first.clientHeight;
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2dGn4/11/)

I've also used `top` and `left` with `position:absolute` for positioning, as this take the element out of the page flow and I assume this is the behaviour you are looking for.

References:

- [offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetHeight)
- [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.clientHeight)

(Follow the links and take a look at the box-model diagrams)

Answer (score 1):

Reason is drawing round take **`3px`** thats why not positioning but you divide 2.1 that result come that you need.

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2dGn4/8/)**</kbd>

#### JavaScript

```
var first = document.getElementsByClassName('first')[0];
var second = document.getElementsByClassName('second')[0];
var height = first.offsetHeight;
second.style.width = height/2.1+"px";
second.style.height = height/2.1+"px";
second.style.marginLeft = height/4+"px";
second.style.marginTop = height/4+"px";
```

Answer (score 0):

var second = document.getElementsByClassName('second')[0];`
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(100/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(100/2);
    second.style.width = "100px"; //set as per your requirement
    second.style.height = "100px"; //set as per your requirement
    second.style.left= left +"px";
    second.style.top = top +"px";

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, you're interested, I tried to come up with a CSS only solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/53M6A/1/
Here's the changes I made to the .second class.

```
.second{
    left: 50%; //move 50% to left
    top: 50%; // move 50% down
    margin-left: -50px; //move half of it's own size back to the left
    margin-top: -50px; //move half of it's own size back to the top
    position: relative; //make it relative, so it can be moved around by left/top
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing a little in your fiddle and finally, I changed your 2 last lines for these:

```
first.style.display = "table-cell";
first.style.verticalAlign = "middle";
second.style.margin = "0 auto";
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhalcojor/95Bvp/1/)

Seems perfectly centered to me.